# Importing CSV file in SQLITE3 results in a blinking cursor with no action!

Tags: sqlite

I ran the following command in SQLITE3 command line tool.

```
sqlite> .import out.txt Test
```

And the following is the result:

```
sqlite> .import out.txt Test
   ...>
```

"...>" keeps showing up if I hit enter. It looks like it's expecting another parameter, except I can't find anything on Google.

Thanks always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, sqlite3's `.import` expects tab-delimited data. You can change it with `.separator`.

An example:

```
$ cat >data.txt
1,2,3
$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.5.1
Enter ".help" for instructions
sqlite> create table t(a integer, b integer, c integer);
sqlite> .separator ,
sqlite> .import data.txt t
sqlite> select a from t;
1
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Now I am stuck in that "...>" command line. I can't get myself out from there haha. I tried ".quit" but it didn't work.

Comment: It's waiting for the input to complete. Semicolon `;` works many times as it completes a SQL clause. Otherwise Control-C or just kill the sqlite3 process.